# Tabs are above my sherlock action bar

Tags: tabs, actionbarsherlock

I use ActionBarSherlock. Everything would be OK if my action bar were above the tabs.

```
public class MyList extends SherlockListActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.countries_list);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        // Inflating tabs and views

    }

    // onTab methods
}
```

[image: Screetshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the framework that was only fixed in Android 4.2. ActionBarSherlock displays the same behavior as Android 4.0 for consistency. Even if it was fixed in ABS you'd still see this broken behavior on 4.0 and 4.1 in your apps.

Comment: I was misteken when writing my previous comments. I've compiled Android action bar and got the tabs above the action bar once.